# Leaflet L.geoJSON.getLatLng() is not a function

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to get latlang of a marker so I can use it and fly to later.

```
map.flyTo(myLayer.getLatLng() ,16);
```

But why do I get getLatLng() not a function?

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/GitMorin/pen/VGdYWW)

Comment: that method is implemented for singular leaflet feature objects (*[circle]marker, popup, polyline*) only, not for a layer object (if I interpret `myLayer` correctly)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getLatLng()` is not a method of [`L.geoJSON`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#geojson). As far as I can see you have three options (in the order of what I would do):

#### 1. Directly access the coordinates of the `geojsonFeature`:

```js
var coord = geojsonFeature.geometry.coordinates;
map.flyTo([coord[1],coord[0]]); // inverted
```

#### 2. Use the `getBounds()` method:

```js
map.flyTo(myLayer.getBounds().getCenter());
```

#### 3. Fly to the circle marker at (actually *before*) creation:

```js
let myLayer = L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature, {
      pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        map.flyTo(latlng);
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

PS.: Your codepen example has a typo: `getLatLang()` should be `getLatLng()`.

Edit: Include @til_b's hint on `LatLngBounds` [`getCenter()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#latlngbounds-getcenter).

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on @Stefan_Fairphones answer and also add some minimal code example:

To fly to the feature on an event, use

```
document.getElementById("fly").addEventListener("click", function() {
  map.flyTo(myLayer.getBounds().getCenter(), 16);
});
```

I would always prefer the get-Methods over accessing "private" properties directly, but thats mainly style.

See corrected codepen at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QZLMNg .

This needs some HTML element with the id `fly`, which i have added in the codepen.

Also, o a side note: If you don't need multiple features you could scrap the geojson completely and use markers directly:

```
  L.marker([41.77,-88.15]).addTo(map);
```

Markers can also use custom icons, see https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#divicon . Note the different order of the coordinates in the marker constructor from the geojson!